# Mocking frameworks for .NET on Monotouch?

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, mocking

Has anyone been using a .NET mocking framework that they have found compatible with Monotouch? I am curious about compatibility with NMock, NSubstitute, Moq and other frameworks before I attempt to use one.

Xamarin just beefed up its unit testing support, but no mention of a mock framework. FYI, I am hoping to do a lot of my development on VS 2010 for the non-UI bits and move to the iOS platform when the UI comes into play.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I (as the Touch.Unit author) have not heard to anyone using them. If you don't get specific answers I encourage you to try them (the open source ones at least) on MonoTouch and create your own answer here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking framework for use with xamarin android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538727/mocking-framework-for-use-with-xamarin-android)

Comment: I assume `FakeItEasy` doesn't work in this environment? Putting it here as you didn't mention it in your initial post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend  just using manual mocking:

```
interface IClass {
    void Method(int x);
}

MockClass : IClass {
     public void Method(int x) {
          MethodParameter = x;
     }

     //Assert against this guy
     public int MethodParameter { get; private set; }
}

StubClass : IClass {
     public void Method(int x) {
          //Do nothing
     }
}
```

If I had to guess Rhino Mocks, Moq, etc. have heavy usage of Reflection.Emit (how else could you do the craziness they can do?), which will not run with the AOT compiler on MonoTouch.

Comment: Thanks. Manual mocking is something I have done a lot of in the past, but was wondering if any frameworks were compatible across platforms. Manual mocking tends to be a bit more work, although there are lots of good dependency injection patterns to make it easy.

Comment: TinyIoC has worked well for us in MonoTouch to help with IoC/DI: https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC

Comment: This is so disappointing. I wanted to use Moq so bad on a MonoTouch project.

Comment: This is a limitation imposed by apple not allowing dynamic code generation. So mocking frameworks are not possible, without Reflection.Emit.

Comment: I looked up the limitation - its recorded here - http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/ - Thanks @jonathanpeppers for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Try [TrueFakes](http://truefakes.net/)!
It can mock public interfaces.