# Mocking framework for use with xamarin android

Tags: android, mocking, xamarin

I am trying to find a mocking framework that works with Xamarin Android. So far I have tried Rhino Mocks and Moq but both depend on System.Web.dll which does not seem to be supported by Xamarin. I have included the System.Web.Services reference to my project with no luck.

So my question is what mocking frameworks out there are compatible with Xamarin projects? This is just for simple mocking not even specific android classes like activities, although one that could combine both would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've observed, there really is no mocking frameworks that work well with Xamarin. On the iOS side, this is mainly due to the inability to use Reflection.Emit because of the code generation restriction imposed by Apple. I realize you're on Android, so that restriction does not apply to you. However, other restrictions arise, like you've found with RhinoMocks. My favorite mocking framework is Moq, but I can't use it with Xamarin because of some of the configuration namespaces that are implemented in .NET, but not in Mono.

So, your best bet is just manual mocks. I know that's not the answer you want to hear, but it seems to be the consensus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hopefully soon they will create a mocking framework for use with Xamarin. For now I have started manual mocking as you have suggested.

Comment: I have just released LightMock that enables mocking on iOS and Android. https://github.com/seesharper/LightMock

Answer (score 3):

You can use True Fakes (http://truefakes.net) mocking framework to solve your issues. It doesn’t use Reflection.Emit at runtime, but it automatically generates mocks at compile time and add it to assembly where unit-tests are. This allows you to use True Fakes for writing unit tests with fully isolated system under test for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS and running them directly on the device!

You can add it to your project via NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/TrueFakes/).
Please see more information about True Fakes at http://truefakes.net.

PS. I’m developer of True Fakes mocking framework.

Comment: can it mock statics?

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible to mock statics, sealed etc in Xamarin. Now it mocks only interfaces, but it will support virtual and abstract classes soon as well.

Comment: @alexander.samuilov I cannot purchase a license as your https://account.truefakes.net/Account/Register/ ... I am very interested in using this as I experience Reflection.Emit issues using other Mocking frameworks

Comment: @XamDev89 please consider to use latest version (2.5.0.601) of TrueFakes since it is free and doesn't require registering.

Comment: @XamDev89 btw, what kind of issues you are experiencing using other Mocking frameworks?

Comment: @alexander.samuilov When adding Mocking frameworks such as Moq or NSubstitute to our Net Core testing project we were experiencing issue's w/ Castle.Core and Reflection.Emit. As you may already know Castle.Core is a dependency for these frameworks. Basically what would happen is this error would appear before our NUnit test runner apps had a chance to launch in debug mode.

Comment: @alexander.samuilov I will also mention that our Net Core test project obviously had a reference to our Xamarin Net Standard 2.0 project. That being said I know there is some rumble w/ NetStandard 2.0 + and Reflection.Emit  --> https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29365

Comment: website is down.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a mock generator called PCLMock.
I had to fork it to get it working with .netstandard, you can give it a go by cloning it and building it from here:
https://github.com/pellet/PCLMock

It works by generating code before compile time, therefore not needing the reflection apis missing in AOT compiled xamarin projects.

Otherwise you could always go functional style and pass in your dependencies as delegates/Funcs, this way you don't need to generate mocks for interfaces, you can use a builder class for injecting mocked out lambdas in unit tests.